# barButtonItem for splitViewController not shown on screen?

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

how does the barButtonItem from the SplitViewController can be shown? isn't automatically created with the splitViewController?

i created a projet targeted for Ipad, i put my mainViewController as the controller view to be on screen in portrait mode, and i created another uiviewController "RootViewController" with its tableView.

i put the two methods :

```
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:
```

in my mainViewController, for example :

```
// Called when rotating to a portrait orientation.
- (void)splitViewController: (UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc 
{
    barButtonItem.title = @"Root List";
    NSMutableArray *items = [[toolbar items] mutableCopy];
    [items insertObject:barButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
    [items release];
    self.mainPopoverController = pc;
}
```

(mainPopoverC... is set in the .h file :

> UIPopoverController *mainPopoverController;

)

but the simulation only shows the mainViewController view whitout the barButtomItem.

Any idea?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your toolbar contains no items,

```
[toolbar items]
```

is nil, so your mutableCopy goes into deep space ...

Comment: thanks Tom, yeah so same question actually, i tried chown's code and the toolbar seems to be empty : how would you do normally? i set up the splitVC with IB, the viewController appears, but not the toolbar... isn't it automatically added by any method i should add to the code?

Comment: Did you setup this by yourself? I suggest you try the SplitView template project and check the differences. The detailview has a toolbar there, it isn't created automatically.

Comment: you're right, the toolbar is added to the screen... i didn't see that, thanks, it works now ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this inside `willHideViewController`:

```
UIBarButtonItem *menuButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Root List" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showPopover:)];
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:toolbar.items];
if ([items count]) {
    [items insertObject:menuButtonItem atIndex:0];
    [toolbar setItems:items];
}
[menuButtonItem release];
[items release];
```

Comment: thanks, yeah it is indeed empty, at least it seems to be empty because nothing appears on screen. How would you do normally? i set up the splitVC with IB, the viewController appears, but not the toolbar...

Comment: make sure your not doing something like this: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;` or `toolbar.hidden = YES;` in the `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.

Comment: okay i had to put the toolbar myself on the view, my mistake. thanks for your help!